# code tag doesn't occupy 100% of the parent pre tag height

Tags: html, css, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I am using HighlightJS to highlight my code. How do I reset the spacing between pre and code tags (marked with the gray background)? I set both the padding and margin of both pre and code tags to 0 but that doesnt seem to work. Ideally I would like the code tag to occupy the complete height of the pre tag. Could you please let me know how I can do that?

```css
pre{
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

code{
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.4.0/styles/color-brewer.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.4.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
<pre>
  <code class="html">
      &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
      &lt;html&gt;
      &lt;title&gt;HTML Tutorial&lt;/title&gt;
      &lt;body&gt;

      &lt;h1&gt;This is a heading&lt;/h1&gt;
      &lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;

      &lt;/body&gt;
      &lt;/html&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you remove this line break from your code :

```
<pre>
  <code class="html">
```

like this :

```
<pre><code class="html">
```

or you reset the white space properties of those 2 tags :

```css
pre{
  background: gray;
  white-space:normal;
}

pre code{
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.4.0/styles/color-brewer.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.4.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
<pre>
  <code class="html">
      &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
      &lt;html&gt;
      &lt;title&gt;HTML Tutorial&lt;/title&gt;
      &lt;body&gt;

      &lt;h1&gt;This is a heading&lt;/h1&gt;
      &lt;p&gt;This is a paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;

      &lt;/body&gt;
      &lt;/html&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```